# Match Email address format with regex

Tags: python, regex, email, match

I know there are multiple discussions about the topic of matching email format. Examples are:

- [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)
- [Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works.](https://emailregex.com/)
- [Extracting email addresses using regular expressions in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extracting-email-addresses-using-regular-expressions-python/)

Despite of this I was not able to copmplete my Python Regex in a way that it matches every example which I have collected. In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJcEXt/4) you can find all possible valid and not valid email formats with focus on Germany (.de), Austria (.au) and international (.com).

The best regex to match my examples so far is:

```
^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$
```

**EDIT:**
Based on fist user comments many user say my demo is to complexe. Here is a more simple one [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJcEXt/3).

Comment: did you try to long regex as well?

Comment: No, what do you mean with that?

Comment: ```[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}```

Comment: this answer has a long regex that should solve it for ya: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1903368/13000953\

Comment: best validation is to send an email with secret code that they need to respond to ;-)

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Yes, I have tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: @JerryAn As you can see in my demo, you solution doesn't match all cases.

Comment: Match all cases is impossible, you should keep a balance between valid cases and invalid cases @PParker

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh It doesn't work at all: https://regex101.com/r/MZSYVV/1

Comment: Looking at your demo data, why are `_test@gmail.com` or `t.e.st@gmail.com` invalid ?

Comment: That's an issue with your checker, that it requires to escape all the quotation marks

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Ah, you think these are valid emails? Okay, then I will change my demo in my first post. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PParker: Why at all, do you want to match them ?

Comment: Well, my chatbot is validating email addresses from customers in Germany and Austria. I thought these would be the most common cases for email addresses for people in these countries. Is this too much? Is this unrealistic?

Comment: I have added a more simple demo

Comment: Why is `email@example.web` invalid?

Comment: well, you think it is valid? I will change it!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are the master of regex. You think it is possible to find a perfectly matching regex for my master demo? Or should we stick with the simplified demo?

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is example-based only. Regex is a rule-based thing, you should provide exact requirements. Else, "lemme-change-the-examples-and-it-will-work" makes little sense for future visitors. https://regex101.com/r/7Wrloe/1 will work, I think, for these examples. But with that demo, I am answering another question already.

Comment: Ok, more rules, less examples. I will remember it for the future. 

If you think your approache is good, I will take it. Looks good to me on the first glance!

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part it appears that the problem is a little bit more complex than what you examples tend to  show.

Comment: @hpchavaz Thank you very much for your link. Email addresses are much more complexe than I thought. Very interesting!

Comment: @PParker, and what seems weird can be useful. For instance  Google gmail accepts adresses in the form "name+xxx@gmail.com" for the account "name@gmail.com" : the 'xxx' can then be use to filter incoming emails , but unfortunately many sites do not accept these types of address.